# I put code of laravel in my cpanel and did connection with db in .env file but when i searched url https://eduvision.umairriaz.site/

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp, composer-php

[image]

I added a photo. When I am going to public folder, then it's showing everything.

Comment: the webroot is supposed to point to the `public` folder of the project

Comment: Please share more details - is there any error message involved, or any code? Share it as text, not hidden in an image

Answer (score 1):

you should add rules in .htaccess

```
<Files ~ "\.(env|json|config.js|md|gitignore|gitattributes|lock)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 403 /404
```